# problem when trying to login in Django Admin

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have a legacy database which uses Unix time and I have override an absractbaseuser. here is my model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser,BaseUserManager
from django.contrib.auth.signals import user_logged_in
from .helper import get_current_unix_timestamp


class MyUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, username,password=None):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given email, date of
        birth and password.
        """
        if not username:
            raise ValueError('user must have a username')

        user = self.model(
            username=username,
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, username, password=None):
        """
        Creates and saves a superuser with the given email, date of
        birth and password.
        """
        user = self.create_user(
            username,
            password=password,
        )
        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True,verbose_name='ID',)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True,unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    ip = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True,blank=True)
    date_registered = models.IntegerField(default=get_current_unix_timestamp())
    last_login = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
    member_group_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    credits = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    notes = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    reseller_dns = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    owner_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    override_packages = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    hue = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    theme = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    timezone = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    api_key = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True, null=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    objects = MyUserManager()
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'


    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'users'
        ordering = ['username']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

what I have done to insert Enix time in my last_login is to change behavior of Django signal user_logged_in like this . the get_current_unix_timestamp() is a sample function that convert to Unix timestamp

```
def update_last_login(sender, user, **kwargs):
    """
    A signal receiver which updates the last_login date for
    the user logging in.
    """
    user.last_login = get_current_unix_timestamp()
    user.save(update_fields=['last_login'])


user_logged_in.connect(update_last_login)
```

the get_current_unix_timestamp function :

```
import datetime

def get_current_unix_timestamp():
    """this function retrun a unix format datetime"""
    return int(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%s'))
```

when I try to login in Django Admin I get this error

```
TypeError at /admin/login/
Field 'last_login' expected a number but got datetime.datetime(2021, 12, 26, 11, 35, 3, 605827).
```

Answer (score 0):

As per our model, you are teh IntegerField for Datetime field

try replacing

```
date_registered = models.IntegerField(default=get_current_unix_timestamp())
last_login = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
```

with

```
date_registered = models.DateTimeField("your settins here")
last_login = models.DateTimeField("your settins here")
```

Comment: the problem is in the last_login not in date_registered and I would not change my database structure because there is another system that use it

Comment: not working for me when I change to datetimefield .

Comment: @mginside: you can try the timestamp if you want to.

Comment: when i change IntegerField to DateTimefield it affect my database . when i try to login it perform my wish datetime in unix normaly but can't access admin django dashboard

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong,
1. you want to enter the lastLogin of user in datetime format in your db and for that you have created a IntegerField in your model.
2. Now the prboblem is when you are entering the datetime instead of integer, you have got an error i.e. "TypeError". (as per your error console)

Comment: i have created last_login as integer field because there is another system that used this format . when i try to login it perform last_login as integer normaly but can't access django admin dashboard the error is

Comment: "get_current_unix_timestamp" as per this,
respective function creates the "timeStamp", thats the reason you're getting the integer value. 
To access this time you need to convert the timestamp into datetime format or vice-versa

Comment: any other help please ?